# Phone number list manipulation Nested SED

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

Still about phone manipulation.
I have a list of phone numbers as per below:

```
(855) 422-6932
(899) 991-9054
(855) 912-7326
(833) 390-8072
(867) 934 2368
(898) 731 7056
(899) 251 5372
(855) 137-6285
(855) 294-5537
(844) 680-7479
```

If you notice the phone number pattern on line number 5 to 7 it has no "-" 
how can I insert "-" using sed or awk?

It feels like i will have to do some sort of nested sed conditional substitution if it is possible at all.

can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is close to other question you have asked.  Try modify what you have.

```
awk '!/-/ {$0=$1 " " $2 "-" $3}1'
(855) 422-6932
(899) 991-9054
(855) 912-7326
(833) 390-8072
(867) 934-2368
(898) 731-7056
(899) 251-5372
(855) 137-6285
(855) 294-5537
(844) 680-7479
```

Comment: Hi Jotne, this is working thank you... but I am having a hard time trying to understand the logic flow on this? what does this {$0=$1 " " $2 "-" $3} means?

Comment: $0 is the complete string.  $1 is the first filed (855) $2 is the second and so on. So recreate $0 using first filed, plus second filed then - then third filed.

Answer (score 4):

You could just tell `sed` to substitute the second space to a hyphen:

```
sed 's/ /-/2' file
```

Results:

```
(855) 422-6932
(899) 991-9054
(855) 912-7326
(833) 390-8072
(867) 934-2368
(898) 731-7056
(899) 251-5372
(855) 137-6285
(855) 294-5537
(844) 680-7479
```

Comment: Thank You Steve this is Awesome ! so I am guessing the 2 specifies the field number in the output?

Comment: @HutanRimba: No. `sed` is a stream editor; the `2` defines the occurrence; so it will act on the second occurrence (if any) of the regex. In your example input, there can only be a maximum of two spaces per line. If you want to play around with fields, use `awk`.

Comment: +1 - I never remember you can tell sed what occurrence number to use.

Answer (score 1):

Use this perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe "s/(\(\d{3}\) \d{3})[ -](\d{4})/$1-$2/g" <in.txt >out.txt
```

Depending on OS and shell, you may need to use single quotes to preserve backslashes and $ chars.

Answer (score 1):

Using perl, you can essentially rewrite each line using the correct format. I assume there are exactly 3 groups of digits on each line:

```
perl -ne 'printf "(%s) %s-%s\n", (/\d+/g)' file
```

use `-i` for in-place editing of the file